# How to test a project downloaded from github in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Im new to Android Studio and Github and would like some guidance. I am wanting to include a github project into a Android app i am building and use its functions, but want to first test it before linking it to my app

This is the project i want to include in my app:
https://github.com/Philipinho/CoinGecko-Java

i successfully imported its as a new project in Android Studio using the Import from Version Control menu. I now want to test the code in the test directory e.g. CoinsExample.java, but im not sure what to for that. Is there a way i can just run it and output the results in a console?

Also ive been reading about Gradle, and wonder why this project does not have a gradle file? Will i need it if i want to add it to my own Android app project?

Thank you for reading

David

Comment: It is a maven project so it doesn't have any .gradle files :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This repository does not contain an Android application. It is a Java library built with Maven. All files in `test\....` directory have the `main()` method so you can run them separately. (I'm not sure if you can run them in Android Studio but you can run them in Eclipse or any other Java IDE) If you want to use it in your Android application, you should first add this to your root `build.gralde` :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

then add you can add this dependency to your project :

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.Philipinho:CoinGecko-Java:e5a72c7083'
}
```

Comment: @ Omid.N Thanks for this, just what i needed to going. Regarding the code, where are the values 'https://jitpack.io' and 'e5a72c7083' actually coming from? is it something specific to this library?

Comment: Dear @Mau , `e5a72c7083` is the name of the last commit to the repository and jitpack.io is a website that you can use to add GitHub repos to your Gradle dependency. There are other ways to do it but I prefer it to others. Take a look at this link to find out more : https://jitpack.io/#Philipinho/CoinGecko-Java/e5a72c7083

Answer (score 0):

You just came across a cool library on Github, what do you need to do to test it on your phone?

- Click the download zip
- Extract the zip file
- Open Android Studio
- Import the project you just downloaded
- Sync gradle
- Run the project
- Choose the device you want to run
- Test all you want
- Delete the project folder and the zip file when you don’t want them anymore

Or, you can simply use [dryrun](http://cesarferreira.com/dryrun/)